# Connect one bluetooth device as multiple devices

Tags: c++, c, windows, bluetooth, protocols

I realize that multiple bluetooth devices can be connected to a master device.

My question is simple: can a single bluetooth chip with a single MAC address connect to another bluetooth device *as more than one client*?

**EDIT**:
Basically is it possible to accept multiple bluetooth clients with the same MAC address, if not can the client computer connect using different faux addresses?

For example, I am writing software that emulates a wiimote for the Wii/WiiU. I am hoping to emulate more than a one wiimote using a single bluetooth usb dongle.

If a hack is needed C or C++ code would be prefered.
Preferably for windows if platform dependent.
Please be descriptive in any answers.

Answer (score 1):

Bluetooth HID Spec v1.0

4.4 Multiple Devices per Host/Multiple Hosts per Device

Bluetooth HIDs shall set no limitation on the number of devices per host (up to the seven simultaneous active devices allowed per piconet). All trusted devices (devices that have either been authenticated or have no security procedures required) shall be allowed to have simultaneous connections to the host, if the host so desires. For example, multiple Bluetooth mice and keyboards are allowed. The behavior in this case shall be the same as for the USB case; i.e., input from all devices is allowed and the data streams are logically ORed together.

Similarly, a single Bluetooth HID may have established a bond or have its address known by multiple hosts. However, if it has declared itself virtually cabled, it is mandatory that the device only support a single host connection, and only one control and one interrupt L2CAP channel to that host, at one time (see SDP attribute HIDVirtualCable). If the device has not declared itself virtually cabled, it is still recommended that the device only support a single host connection at one time, i.e. no more than one SDP, control, and interrupt channel may be open at a time. A Bluetooth HID that implements the Virtual Cable feature shall have sufficient resources to remember a minimum of two hosts, and four hosts is recommended, to make later reconnection easier without passkey entry.

Comment: Multiple SPP service connections between a single host and single client do work. However, unknown if HID will also allow this. Looks like Bluetooth Spec does not recommend this, which would indicate to me that BT stacks may have different allowances. From experience, HID Hosts seem to override certain Bluetooth security settings, perhaps in violation of standards. So, seems like the only way to find out for sure, is to try it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you are asking for but:

A bluetooth network is called piconet, a piconet must have a min number of 2 devices and max 8 devices (7 slaves and 1 master). A device can be the member of one or more piconets but he can be only the master of one of them, this device is called bridge because he blends more piconets in a scatternet.

Therefore you can connect a single bluetooth chip with a single MAC address to more bluetooth devices , but i think you can't connect the same device A as more than one client to the same Master M because when the Master M starts the inquiry phase A will respond with his MAC address and his clock's offset only one time, later during the page phase M and A will establish one connection.